# PyVista plotter unable to produce background image for multiple subplots

Tags: python, pyvista

I am trying to render a mesh in Python using `pyvista.Plotter()` while trying to show images alongside the rendered mesh. The code is currently in the form of

```py
import pyvista as pv
from pyvista import examples

filenames = (['filename1.jpg','filename2.jpg','filename3.jpg',])
mesh = pv.PolyData('meshfile.ply')
p = pv.Plotter(shape='1|3')
p.subplot(0)
p.add_mesh(mesh)
t=1
for i in filenames:
    p.subplot(t)
    p.add_background_image(i)
    #p.add_mesh(examples.load_airplane(), show_edges=False)
    t +=1
```

where I thought the `Plotter.add_background_image()` would be the most convenient way to plot images using PyVista. The commented out line in the `for` loop actually produces the right arrangement but I would like the smaller plots to have background images rather than another mesh. However, only the final image file is actually shown and it is the background image of `p.subplot(0)` which should not have a background image. Would there be a more convenient way of displaying images alongside a pyvista 3d-rendered window?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation of `Plotter.add_background_image()`](https://docs.pyvista.org/plotting/plotting.html#pyvista.BasePlotter.add_background_image):

> `add_background_image(image_path, scale=1, auto_resize=True, as_global=True)`
>
> as_global (bool, optional) – When multiple render windows are present, setting `as_global=False` will cause the background to only appear in one window.

So you might just have to call the method as

```py
    p.add_background_image(i, as_global=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I should have known it was global. Meanwhile I figured another method to plot the image is to read it with cv2 as an array and then plot that as a mesh but it seems even less elegant to me, not to mention that the PyVista color scheme is still a mystery to me in terms of meshes.

Comment: @Arttu take a look at https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/00-load/read-image.html: you can easily read images directly into pyvista :)